# PhotoView - calculate appropriate coordinates of pin-tile view depending of displayed matrix

Tags: android, kotlin, android-photoview

Let's assume I have some pin view which I want to render on top of [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) according current scale and zoom (aka simplified TileView).

PhotoView provide method setOnMatrixChangeListener when we zoom or scroll image it will trigger with displayed matrix parameter which is represented as RectF type.

So my question is how properly calculate positioning and scale of pin view on top of PhotoView depending on current zoom and scroll?

```
photView.setOnMatrixChangeListener(object: OnMatrixChangedListener {
   override fun onMatrixChanged(rect: RectF?) {
    // calculation of new coordinates and scale here
     ...
    pinView.x = calculatedCoordinateX;
    pinView.y = calculatedCoordinateY;
    pinView.scale = calculatedScale;
   }
})
```

Any material to study how to use such matrix for such calculation, positioning and scale?

Appreciate if anyone can provide sample code how exactly to solve such problem.

Comment: read carefully  `android.graphics.Matrix` API documentation - there are several `map*()` methods

Comment: @pskink thanks, it could be nice if you also could provide some example code with explanation

Comment: simply use current display matrix: [getDisplayMatrix()](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/blob/master/photoview/src/main/java/com/github/chrisbanes/photoview/PhotoView.java#L167) and try to play with `Matrix#map*()` methods

Comment: for example make a custom `PhotoView` and override its `onDraw` method - call `super.onDraw` and then get current display matrix, call 
`mapPoints` on float array `float[] pts = {200, 400}` and then call `canvas.drawCircle(pts[0], pts[1], 100, paint)` and see where circle is drawn

Comment: @pskink Thank you for your answer I will experiment in the next few days with it. Yes I got your point.

Comment: run [this](https://pastebin.com/U7NHCFJs) sample code, zoom in, scroll a bit and watch two red little dots

Comment: @pskink this code doesn't include scale calculation on current zoom factor. Because the dot should become bigger when we zoom in and smaller when we zoom out. Anyway appreciate your effort to help me out with this problem.

Comment: simply replace `20` with "mapped radius" in `canvas.drawCircle(mappedX, mappedY, 20, paint)`